# Custom page Data render from FPC magento 2

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

I have a custom page which gets data from the block.
FPC is enabled so when I change data it is not reflecting without page cache.

I do not want to use `cacheable="false"` in the block because it will always non-cacheable block.

Basically, I want when There is not data change it will come from the cache and when Data is changing it will reflect at a time.

Magento product page  is using like this to render data change

```
$this->_cacheManager->clean('catalog_product_' . $this->getId());
```

Can i use this way? if yes how can i use this?

How can I do that without ajax? Is it possible to do that?